# How Can I get a Session Id or username in php?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a website where users can log in. I have tried:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION ['userlogin']
```

and When users login I set their session as userlogin, but it won't show their username.
 
[This is the tutorial I used](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/12972-creating-login-registration-forms-php.html)

Answer (score 12):

Did you [start the session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before using it?

So to set it:

```
<?php
   //Fetch the username from the database
   //The $login and $password I use here are examples. You should substitute this
   //query with one that matches your needs and variables.
   //On top of that I ASSUMED you are storing your passwords MD5 encrypted. If not,
   //simply remove the md5() function from below.
   $query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE login='" . mysql_real_escape_string($login) . "' AND password='" . md5($password)  . "'";
   $result = mysql_query($query);

   //Check if any row was returned. If so, fetch the name from that row
   if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc_assoc($result);
      $name = $row['name'];

      //Start your session
      session_start();
      //Store the name in the session
      $_SESSION['userlogin'] = $name;
   }
   else {
      echo "The combination of the login and password do not match".
   }
?>
```

And to retrieve it on another page do:

```
<?php
   //Start your session
   session_start();
   //Read your session (if it is set)
   if (isset($_SESSION['userlogin']))
      echo $_SESSION['userlogin'];
?>
```

**EDIT**

Some more information about how to create a loginform.. You say you tried setting `$_SESSION['user']` but that this didn't work.

So just make sure that you actually did a `session_start();` before that. If you did, everything should work. Unless you assign an empty variable to the session. So doublecheck that the variable you assign actually contains a value. Like:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   echo "Assigning session value to: " . $user;
   $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
?>
```

In the tutorial you linked me to they are doing:

```
$_SESSION[user]=$_GET[userlogin];
```

This means they are assigning a value they got from their loginform that they create here:

```
function loginform() {
   print "please enter your login information to proceed with our site";
   print ("<table border='2'><tr><td>username</td><td><input type='text' name='userlogin' size'20'></td></tr><tr><td>password</td><td><input type='password' name='password' size'20'></td></tr></table>");
   print "<input type='submit' >";    
   print "<h3><a href='registerform.php'>register now!</a></h3>";    
}
```

There you see `<input type='text' name='userlogin' size'20'>`. But there is no `<form></form>` tag around this form.. So this won't properly post. So what you should do is the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
   <label for="userlogin">Username:</label> <input type="text" id="userlogin" name="userlogin" size="20" />
   <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="20" />
   <input type="submit" value="login" />   
</form>
```

This form will post the form back to **index.php** with **userlogin** and **password** as `$_POST` variables.

In your **index.php** you can then do:

```
<?php
   //Get variables:
   $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userlogin']);
   $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

   //Check your table:
   $query = "SELECT userlogin FROM users WHERE userlogin = '" . $login . "' AND password='" . $pass . "'";
   $result = mysql_query($query);

   //Check if this user exists:
   if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
      echo "User exists!";

      //Store the login in the session:
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['userlogin'] = $login;
   }
   else {
      echo "Unknown user";
   }
?>
```

I can't make it much clearer without writing the entire code for you. So I hope this helps you.

Comment: I know that will work but then all of my users will see nick as their username

Comment: The 'nick' was an example because I don't know your code. You just set it with their username (`$username` in my example code). The point in my answer is that you should **start** a session before you can use it (read or write) by using `session_start()`.

Comment: @Nick:The way you have it is wrong.The session variables are stored as cookies in the local user's system and not in the web server,hence the session variable defined for one user will not be available to another.Hope this is what you meant in your comment.

Comment: I have tried the is but it shows up blank. If my database table name is "users" and the table row where I store the usernames is "name", would that make it any different?

Comment: Yes obviously you have to put a value in `$username` before assigning it to your session. Otherwise for sure it'll be blank. Again I'll adapt my answer to give you an example. **NOTE** this code is an EXAMPLE and is not perfect because I don't know all your code, settings, databases, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the help however I am still a bit confused on how to this. I found the tutorial on the login form I used: [Link](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/12972-creating-login-registration-forms-php.html) P.S. I tried $_SESSION[user] but that didn't work.

Comment: I will expand my answer according to the link you gave. Which is not really a good tutorial imo. But ok...

Answer (score 1):

Put session_start(); before the echo

Answer (score 0):

Without showing more code we cant comment much, but are you sure you are calling [session_start](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in each page you use your session variable too? 
Also ensure you are using the same capitalisation (userlogin != UserLogin).